# How to remove clock from Xcode Playground?

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Is there a way to remove the clock from the Xcode Playground top menu?  The clock displays in the center next to "Ready".

[image]

Comment: I don't see a "clock".

Comment: Do you see a "time"?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a clock; it's the time of execution of Xcode's last action (for example, "Build" or "Run"). There is no way to remove it.